# Range restriction on xsd element

Tags: java, xsd, xsd-validation

I need to add restriction on a particular field - phoneNumber.
Rightnow the restriction looks like this :

```
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="phoneNumber">
            <xsd:simpleType>
                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                    <xsd:pattern value="[0-9]{2}[\-][0-9]{10}"/>
                </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
```

So, this would work if the phone number have a value

```
91-1234567890
```

But for a US contact I want the country code is one 1. So, the pattern needs to be changed to `[0-9]{1}[\-][0-9]{10}`

```
1-1234567890
```

So, I have two questions

1. How do I give a specific range in this pattern.
2. Is there a way to decide the pattern during runtime? e.g. If I get the country as India I would keep it as `[0-9]{2}[\-][0-9]{10}` and if I get it as US then I would modify it to `[0-9]{1}[\-][0-9]{10}`

Comment: For second question: Are you asking for conditional branches in xsd or in RegEx?

Comment: @kurellajunior Either way would do. Basically I trying to find if we can decide the pattern during runtime. The decision would be made on the basis of another element in the xsd - country

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully answer to question 1: `[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{10}` or `\d{1,2}-\d{10}`

My favorite RegEx site: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Question 2:

Conditional RegEx: only possible if the data is in the text — this is not the case here

Conditional XSD => I simply redirect you :-)

[How to add conditional validation in XSD :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16813299/how-to-add-conditional-validation-in-xsd)

[xsd property set required according to enum value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16787335/xsd-property-set-required-according-to-enum-value)

Hope, that is what you need, if not we can go deeper here, when you post the part of your xml containing the values in question

Comment: My system shows both as invalid formats - [0-9]{1-2}-[0-9]{10} or \d{1-2}-\d{10}. Did you try it out?

Comment: my mistake. Fixed it above. Happens when doing it from memory :(