# Validating an Element based on the value of an attribute

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I have the following element in my XML

`<xs:MigrationUpgradeRequisitesSection ovf:required="false">
   <Info>Files necessary for migration-based upgrade.</Info>
   <xs:Requisite xs:purpose="requirements" ovf:fileRef="xxxxx"/>
 </xs:MigrationUpgradeRequisitesSection>`

If the `ovf:required=false`, I want to allow the element without doing any validation. Otherwise it should be validated.

How to write xml schema for that? My xml version is 1.0

Comment: You may want to have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16813299/592182

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know it is directly not possible, however, there may be a workaround for your case, as commented in this post:

[Restricting XML Elements Based on Another Element via XSD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4141569/3227554)

The first answer, does a good explanation on why it is not possible, and how to do it by applying a transformation before validating through XSD. You may transform elements with "ovf:required= false" to null elements before XSD validation.