# xsd: force attribute in element iff child-element is present

Tags: xml, xsd, keyref

suppose I have two elements, where the first (`register`) may contain several of the second (`scale`). The `@unit` attribute of the `scale` element is a `xs:key` (hence unique inside the first element). It *can* be named as a `xs:keyref` in a "defaultScale" attribute of the `register` element. Like this:

```
<xs:element name="register">
  <xs:key name="scaleKey">
    <xs:selector xpath="scale" />
    <xs:field xpath="@unit" />
  </xs:key>
  <xs:keyref name="chooseDefaultScale" refer="scaleKey">
    <xs:selector xpath="."/>
    <xs:field xpath="@defaultScale"/>
  </xs:keyref>
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element ref="scale"/>
      </xs:choice>
    <xs:attribute name="defaultScale" type="xs:string" />
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="scale">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:attribute name="scale" type="xs:float" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="unit" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

How can I force the `@defaultScale` attribute to be present and valid *iff* at least one `scale` child is present?

My first try was to add another `xs:key` into the base-element of `register`, like in `try1` and `try2`. Both don't compile...

```
<xs:element name="body">
  <xs:key name="try1">
    <xs:selector xpath=".//register/defaultScale" />
    <xs:field xpath="../@defaultScale" />             <!-- not allowed -->
  </xs:key>
  <xs:key name="try2">
    <xs:selector xpath=".//register[defaultScale]" /> <!-- not allowed -->
    <xs:field xpath="@defaultScale" /> 
  </xs:key>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element ref="register"/>
  <xs:sequence>
</xs:element>
```

I am only allowed to use the child-axis in the `xs:selector` and `xs:field` elements. So my best guess in the moment: It's not possible?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question: not possible out-of-the-box, have to use XSD 1.1. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16787335/xsd-property-set-required-according-to-enum-value) for example.

Note that this is not trivial from a debian shell using foss software...