# Check value of an XML element in an XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, conditional-statements, element, required

I want to check a XML-Element-Value in the XSD, if the Element has a specific value an other value must be required in the XML.

Example:

```
<root>
  <Element1>test</Element1>
  <Element2>value</Element2>
</root>
```

Now I want to check in the XSD if the value of Element1 is "test", when the condition is true Element2 the Element must be required.

Is this possible?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you seen this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16787335/xsd-property-set-required-according-to-enum-value

Comment: I think in that example the Element-Name is checked. In my case i have to check the value of the element. Is that possible?